# Why i not get same value with $x and $y PHP var?

Tags: php, floor

When i tested this code , i get `$x = 29` and `$y = 30`
.

.

```
<?PHP
$x = "0.0003";
$x = $x*100000;
$x = floor($x);
echo $x;
?>

<br>

<?PHP 
$y = "30";
$y = floor($y);
echo $y;
?>
```

Why `$x` not `30` ? what's happen ?

How can i do for get `$x = 30`

Comment: [Read, learn and understand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems)

Comment: Here you are a [better test case](https://repl.it/INZb/0).